# I want to sort listView according to MRP

Tags: android

Scenario: I  want to sort listview . I have also 0.00 Mrp in  items .
I  have arrange list items in accending order according  to MRP which are in  double.  But  also I have  to  show items  with 0.00 Mrp's  at the bottom of all items.

```
Collections.sort(productList, new Comparator<NewItemDataset>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(NewItemDataset lhs, NewItemDataset rhs) {
                        return lhs.getMrp().compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.getMrp());
                    }
                });
```

I am using above  code for  sorting

Can anybody solve  this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  Collections.sort(productList, new Comparator<NewItemDataset>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(NewItemDataset lhs, NewItemDataset rhs) {
                            return Double.compare(lhs.getMrp(), rhs.getMrp());
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Its is sorting right sir  but  how  to  show 0.0 items at  bottom of list

Comment: Use `Collections.reverse`

Comment: I  want to sort first in  ascending and then zero mrp items at  bottom ?